# How to use SSH access via Bitbucket pipeline for deployment

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, deployment, bitbucket

I am creating script for automatic testing and publishing. Everything works for me, except one thing. I can't do this command `git fetch origin` without using a password. I tried to set an access key in Bitbucket. I already set one in the server, but it doesn't work. Can you please help me? For clarity, I show you my script and my pipeline.

My Bitbucket pipeline:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:7.2.24-fpm

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y unzip libpng-dev libxml2-dev libmagickwand-dev libbz2-dev
          - echo "memory_limit = 512M" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
          - pecl install imagick
          - docker-php-ext-install bz2
          - docker-php-ext-enable imagick
          - docker-php-ext-install xml
          - docker-php-ext-install mbstring
          - docker-php-ext-install gd
          - docker-php-ext-install zip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/phpunit
#  custom:
#    deploy-branch-develop-to-server:
#      - step:
#          name: Deploy to server branch develop
#          script:
#          - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
#            variables:
#              SSH_USER: $USER
#              SERVER: $SERVER
#              SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
#              MODE: 'script'
#              COMMAND: 'scripts/deploy-develop.sh'
#  branches:
#    develop:
#      - step:
#          name: Deploy to server branch develop
#          script:
#            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
#              variables:
#                SSH_USER: $USER
#                SERVER: $SERVER
#                SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
#                MODE: 'script'
#                COMMAND: 'scripts/deploy-develop.sh'
#    master:
#      - step:
#          name: Deploy to server branch master
#          script:
#            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.6
#              variables:
#                SSH_USER: $USER
#                SERVER: $SERVER
#                SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
#                MODE: 'script'
#                COMMAND: 'scripts/deploy-master.sh'
```

My deployement script:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/am-develop

sudo -u www-data cp .env.develop .env
sudo -u www-data git fetch origin # DOES NOT WORK!
sudo -u www-data composer install
sudo -u www-data npm run development
chown www-data:www-data -R .
service apache2 restart
service supervisor restart
php artisan elaborate:apps
wall "Deploy completed in production"
```